# Flask raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')

Tags: python, веб-программирование, flask

Всем привет. У меня есть проект со следующей структурой

```
├── app
   ├── api  
   │   │   
   │   └── views.py
   ├── config.py
   ├── __init__.py 
   ├── requirements.txt
   ├── tests   
   │   └── test_api.py
   ├── uwsgi.ini
   └── wsgi.py
```

Файл wsgi.py вход в приложение.

```
from __init__ import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   app.run()
```

В **init**.py файле лежит код в котором я инициализирую подключение конфига.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from config import Settings
from api.views import api_bp   


cors = CORS(resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})

def create_app():
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(Settings)

    cors.init_app(app)

    
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp) 
    
    return app
```

Теперь когда я хочу его вызвать переменную из конфигурационного файла в файле views.py

```
from flask import  Blueprint, app
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import requests
from loguru import logger
from ipwhois import IPWhois
import json
import whois
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from flask import current_app
import re


api_bp = Blueprint('api_v1', __name__)
api_v1 = Api(api_bp)


API_KEY = current_app.config['API_KEY']
```

Я получаю ошибку
raise RuntimeError('working outside of application context')
RuntimeError: working outside of application context

Пытался решить данную ситуацию статьёй из документации, но это не дало результата.
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся и что делаю не так?
Как получить доступ к переменам конфигурации?

Comment: Flask-приложений в теории может быть несколько, и в какое из них должна указывать прокси-переменная `current_app` в данном конкретном случае — неизвестно, оттого и ошибка. Но зачем вам вообще обращаться к конфигурации в глобальном контексте? Что мешает сделать это внутри view-функции, когда application context будет определён?

Comment: Я бы хотел сделать одну точку входа в приложения, и один конфиг файл, как это реализовано в джанго

Comment: Тогда избавьтесь от функции `create_app`, а вместо этого создайте глобальную переменную `app` и используйте везде именно её вместо `current_app`. Однако в Flask так не принято

Comment: Я так понимаю мне всё равно нужно обращаться к фласку приложения и тогда инициализировать 
```` In [4]: app = create_app()

In [5]: app_con = app.app_context()

In [6]: app_con. push()

In [7]: from flask import current_app

In [8]: current_app.name
Out[8]: '__init__'
````
Через ipython я получил желаемый результат, но это только если обращаться напрямую в корень и определять application context

Comment: Хорошо, а как правильно делать во фласке?
Вот здесь человек реализует данную схему
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/__init__.py
Плюс в документации фласка по бестпрактис указанно именно так

Comment: Правильно — не обращаться к `current_app` в глобальном контексте, и подобных ошибок возникать не будет. Что вам мешает прочитать API_KEY в локальном контексте внутри view-функции?

Comment: По сути ничего, просто хотел реализовать один конф на апку

Comment: Ну он и так один конф `current_app.config`, просто не используйте его в глобальном контексте и всё

Comment: Прошу прощения, а можно подробнее.
Я что не могу понять как я обращаюсь в глобальном контексте, а как обратиться в локальном контексте

Comment: Просто не используйте current_app за пределами view-функций

Comment: Да, действительно все заработало.
Но это есть нормальная практика, что flask application  будет вызываться и во вью?
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Settings)

api_bp = Blueprint('api_v1', __name__)
api_v1 = Api(api_bp)

API_KEY = app.config['API_KEY']

Comment: То есть если у меня будет 4 каталога со своими вью, то нормально что в каждом из них будет вызван Flask&

Comment: Конечно не нормально. Зачем так делать, если можно просто использовать current_app внутри view-функций? Я не понимаю, что вы пытаетесь мудрить

Comment: Так окей, мы кажись не понимаем друг друга во все.
Что по Вашему  view-функция?
Я хочу просто определить в инит файле конфиг файл, как и писал выше, а потом обратиться к нему через current_app

Что значит "использовать  current_app внутри view-функций"

Comment: «Что по Вашему view-функция?» — ну вот когда вы тут напишите что-то вроде `@api_bp.route('foo')` `def foo():` получится view-функция (другими словами, «представление» или просто «вьюха») foo, которая будет запускаться при обращении к адресу `/api_v1/foo` и внутри которой current_app будет замечательно работать. // «определить в инит файле конфиг файл» — не надо так делать, у вас есть конфиг в `current_app.config`, вот его и используйте внутри view-функций по необходимости.

Comment: Если говорить про flask_restful, то там по сути то же самое: вы создаёте `class Foo(Resource)` и внутри него определяете методы get/post и прочие, которые по сути являются теми же вьюхами и внутри которых current_app тоже будет замечательно работать, то есть какое-нибудь `class Foo(Resource): def get(self): API_KEY = current_app.config['API_KEY']` работать будет.

Comment: Вот теперь я понял)

Comment: Все работает, спасибо Вам большое за терпения и за то что объяснили)))